# How to know that by clicking on which textfield, the pushing is done

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am new in iOS. I am building a sample project. There are four viewControllers in my project. In the first one there are two textfields. One is for entering country and another is for entering city. Tapping on each of them, pushing to the second viewController is done. In the second, third and fourth viewControllers I have tableViews in each of them.

The table view in the second viewController I have a list of countries, the table view in the third viewController I have a list of states and in the table view in the fourth viewController I have a list of cities.

Tapping on the cells of every tableview pushing is done to the next.

Now my requirement is, when I am tapping on the country textfield the pushing will only done upto the second viewController and when I am tapping on the cities textField pushing will be done upto the fourth viewController.

The thing I want to know is, How to know from which textField the pushing is done.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my first viewController implementation file...

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.txtCity.delegate = self;
    self.txtCountry.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryScene" sender:self];
    } else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryScene" sender:self];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is my second viewController implementation file..

```
#import "CountryViewController.h"

@interface CountryViewController ()

@end

@implementation CountryViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.arrCountries = @[@"India", @"Bangladesh", @"Australia", @"New Zealand", @"South Africa", @"West Indies", @"Sri Lanka", @"England", @"Argentina", @"Brazil"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"countryCell"];

    UILabel *lblCountry = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    lblCountry.text = [self.arrCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.arrCountries count];

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"stateScene" sender: self];
}

@end
```

This is my third viewController implementation file:

```
#import "StateViewController.h"

@interface StateViewController ()

@end

@implementation StateViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.arrStates = @[@"West Bengal", @"Uttar Pradesh", @"Madhya Pradesh", @"Jharkhand", @"Bihar", @"Tamilnadu", @"Myanmar", @"Arunachal Pradesh", @"Assam", @"Goa"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"stateCell"];

    UILabel *lblStates = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    lblStates.text = [self.arrStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.arrStates count];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"cityScene" sender: self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is my fourth viewController implementation file...

```
#import "CityViewController.h"

@interface CityViewController ()

@end

@implementation CityViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.arrCities = @[@"Kolkata", @"Bangalore", @"Chennai", @"Mumbai", @"Hyderabad", @"Mangalore", @"New York", @"London", @"Rio de Janeiro", @"Buenos Aires"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cityCell"];

    UILabel *lblCities = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
lblCities.text = [self.arrCities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.arrCities count];

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showRecipeDetail" sender: self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

Create an instance variable which holds the tag of the selected text field.

```
@interface ViewController() {
    NSInteger tagSelectedTextField;
}
```

In your First `ViewController`, assign tags to your TextFields using `setTag:` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.textCity setTag:1];
    [self.textCountry setTag:2];
    self.txtCity.delegate = self;
    self.txtCountry.delegate = self;
}
```

Now when you in your delegate, check for tags and perform the segue accordingly.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


    if (textField.tag == 1) {

         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cityScene" sender:self];
    } else{

         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryScene" sender:self];
    }
    tagSelectedTextField = textField.tag;
    return YES;
}
```

Now when you come back to this screen or use notification system, use this tag to get back your selected text field by using `[self.view viewWithTag:tagSelectedTextField]` and update the text accordingly.

Comment: I think you haven't understood my question. My question is when I am tapping in each of the textFields the pushing will be done to the viewController named countryScene. But when I am coming from country textfield the pushing will only done upto the country scene and when I am coming from city textField, the pushing will be done upto the last viewController that is the cityScene. 

Actually in my project I want to select the datas from the tableviews to the textFields using nsnotificationcenter.

Comment: But you said if you tap on the second text field it should directly push to 4th view controller i.e. city view controller. The above answer pushes to country view controller if you tap country text field else it will directly push to city view controller

Comment: When I am tapping on country textField it will go like,
Home viewController --> Country viewController. Selecting a country and show it in the country text Field.

When I am tapping on city textField it will go like,

Home viewController--> Country viewController-->State viewController-->City viewController. Selecting a city and show it to the city textField. 

Please once look into this @Sunelwala

Comment: yes thats what, you set a global variable which holds the current tag of the text field. And when you want to update the text field using viewWithTag: method, just call a notification and retrieve the textfield and update its text. This helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already had given tags to textfield.If tag is 1 then Country textfield otherwise its city textfield.By identifying tag u can switch to respective view controllers.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

 if (textField.tag == 1) {
 //Country view Controller
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"countryScene" sender:self];
}
 else{
//City View Controller   
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cityScene" sender:self];
}

  return YES;
}
```